# Capistrano task to start Sinatra

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have a simple Sinatra app which I run locally by `rackup -p 9210' command and I want to write a capistrano task which, after deployment to my server, will start my Sinatra app just I would do locally.

Here'is my task:

```
desc 'Start application'
  task :start do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      within '/my/app/folder/' do
        execute "rackup -p 9210"
    end
  end
end
```

but it errors out with the message:

```
Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rackup -p 9210 exit status: 127
rackup -p 9210 stdout: Nothing written
rackup -p 9210 stderr: bash: rackup: command not found
```

I have tried executing this command:

```
desc 'Start application'
  task :start do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
       execute "cd /my/app/folder/ && rackup -p 9210"
    end
  end
end
```

but got the same error message. 
My Cap file:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'

set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.0p0'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you have the gem `rack`? maybe `bundle exec rackup` instead?

Comment: do I need the gem rackup? I don't have it locally, neither in my Gemfile but it works locally. Do I need it?

Comment: When I `ssh` onto the remote server and do `rackup -p 9210` it works perfectly fine.

Comment: It may be that capistrano uses different user than you are. Presumably it's `deploy`. Maybe check `rackup` availability for `deploy` user?

Comment: I don't have a deploy user at this time. It's root.

Comment: `which rvm`: /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm, `which rackup`: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rackup. Everything set up correctly so why does this task not work?